# How can I dynamically enable/disable series tooltip based on point condition

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with a lot of series, showing all series on tooltips is not a good solution, because chart `div` is small and it makes some tooltips to get cropped from `plotArea`.

Each `series` of the data correspond to a year, and each point of each `series` is a month. In my case I have series from the last couple decades. The solution I found would be to display for each point (month) only the last 2 years (2 most important series being analyzed) and the series with minimum and maximum values.
I couldn't find anything on docs to help me achieve this, using `enableMouseTracking` disable the series completely from tooltip, I think I would need to enable/disable it dynamically, is there a custom tooltip workaround to implement my idea?

**EDIT**
I managed to print only the values I want, does anybody know a way to remove those empty tooltips? I'm returning `null` using `pointFormatter` on their case.
[image]

**CLOSED**
I achieved what I wanted returning `false`

Comment: Is your CLOSED statement to indicate that you've found a solution and don't need further help? If so, answers go down there, not in your question, and don't forget to accept yours to resolve the post. If not, please clarify what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted returning `false`